# In what order do the specials chapters show up for Wagatsuma-san wa Ore no Yome

Tags: wagatsuma-san-wa-ore-no-yome

There are currently 11 translated specials and 25 translated chapters.
I'm not sure what order I should be reading these chapters in?

Comment: Per my answer in your other question, it looks like the publication order is "all of the chapters from Special followed by all of the chapters from the Weekly Shounen", but I haven't actually read this manga, so I'm not going to make that an answer.